# Can RNA assisted protein folding be performed computationally?

Tags: simulation

I am looking for tools/ softwares to perform protein folding in presence of its RNA partner. Part of my protein is disordered and I suspect that it will take up structure while interacting with its RNA partner. Till now I did not find any literature where computational tools like MD has been implemented to check for such folding.

If anyone has come across any literature or have performed such studies, can you kindly help me how to proceed with it?

Thanking You, Dolly

Answer (score 0):

Is this of any help?

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1232867/

It looks a lot like what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank you for searching the literature. But this literature is the RNA structure coding for the same protein. My protein does not interact with coding RNA. So this literature is not of help.

Answer (score 0):

A 4 year old question, that for some reason the community bot bounced to the top.

Was intrigued, as I am in no way connected to the field, so asked a good friend who is.

She recommended this:

https://www.chemcomp.com/Products.htm

Probably not relevant for OP, but might be of interest to others.